# Swift: UITableViewCell Automatic Row Height For style Subtitle

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have a tableView with 2 sections, the first section is for text the user inputed earlier, the other section for selections based on that text.  The first section has a Default tableViewCell style, the second section has a style of Subtitle.  The first section is just a single cell, and it sizes dynamically based on the amount of text without issue. The second section is multiple cells, with UITableViewCell.textLabel and UITableViewCell.detailText set. These are the cells that do not auto size properly at all, I don't know what I am doing wrong. Note: 1) I do have tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension set in the viewDidLoad() method. 2) I am not using prototype cells in the storyboard.

[This article](http://captechconsulting.com/blog/tyler-tillage/ios-8-tutorial-series-auto-sizing-table-cells) states that I "must have constraints on the contentView". I honestly have no idea what that means. I know what constraints are in terms of setting content on the storyboard. I just don't know what he means in this context or how I would go about that if I don't have prototype cells.

Also, I have to set two re-use identifiers, depending on which section it is. That way it doesn't try to reuse the cell/section I have set aside for the user's input text.

With all that said in mind, here's the code I have. I'm a newbie to Swift and developing for iOS in general so if you have suggestions/advice for refactoring feel free to let me know. I have commented out some things I have tried. Setting the row height to 66 does work, but that's not the goal here. I want it dynamic because I don't know what will change later on.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cellIdentifier = ""
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        //tableView.rowHeight = 66
        //tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        cellIdentifier = "DistortionItem"
    } else {
        //tableView.rowHeight = 160
        cellIdentifier = "NegativeThought"
    }

    var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 1 {


        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }


        cell.textLabel?.text = distortionslist.distortions[indexPath.row].0
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = distortionslist.distortions[indexPath.row].1
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        //tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        //cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
        //cell.detailTextLabel?.sizeToFit()

    } else {

        if cell == nil {
            //println("Cell set to default")
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }

        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
        cell.textLabel?.text = entry.thoughtText
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        //cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
    }

    return cell
}
```

Example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: contentView is a view inside every table view cell inside of which all user created content goes. If you are using a storyboard or nib, you can see the contentView in the Structure editor on the left. You can also access it in code as cell.contentView.

Comment: Is there a way to set restraints with cell.contentView? I can't seem to find anything all that helpful in the documentation or any examples elsewhere. Not sure if this is even the answer.

Comment: I read that article and learned a few things - pretty cool. It says if you are using the default UITableViewCell that the constraints are already set up so it should just work. What isn't working? Can you provide a screenshot?